# Convert Elapsed Timestamp to Float with Logstash

Tags: time, type-conversion, logstash

I have a timestamp in my data that looks like this: 0:00:00.000000

Unfortunately this is supposed to represent elapsed time, and the ELK stack doesn't seem to like that. I need an easy way to convert this to a long/float.

I've looked at the elapsed tag, but I'm not sure I want to run through adding a fake datetime on every iteration just to do a unit conversion. I've also looked into using ruby, but it doesn't seem like strptime is supported.

Comment: I don't understand how your example would look like as a float. Could you give a few input -> output cases?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the grok filter to extract the different parts of the timestamp, then doing the math in ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this the best solution, but I ended up taking the elapsed time field and using split. Then I simply set a new field to:

```
3600*[elapsed time][0] + 60*[elapsed time][1] + [elapsed time][2]
```

This way, a timestamp of 0:01:28.214258 comes out as 88.214258